# Advise On Feeding My Sensitive Cat

Tags: cats, diet

My neutered 6 human years old male cat (Butterscotch) has always had digestive issues and when we finally found a food for him, we were very happy. He still throws up his food occasionally when he eats too fast but this has gotten better with time and he only does it when he is very stressed out. He lives a very happy slightly spoiled life. I was recently told that you should feed your cat wet food. So I tried and he threw up almost instantly after eating it. I tried one with pumpkin (supposed to be better for your cats digestive system.) he still threw up. I gave him three different digestive wet food over a period of time and he still threw up. So finally, I gave up. Now i'm wondering again if I should feed my cat wet food. It is still said that wet food has many benefits. If so how can I get him to digest it!!! Someone asked why I want to switch. I don't want to "switch" I just want to add wet food into his daily meals because of it's health benefits. (or at least supposed health benefits.)

By the way, the food he is on is this.

https://www.royalcanin.com/products/royal-canin-feline-care-nutrition-digestive-care-adult-dry-cat-food/2555

The food he is on has some pretty strange ingredients. I was told that if you wouldn't eat it (aside from the flavour obviously) you shouldn't feed it to your cat. However, maybe this does have the proper nutrients for a cat, I don't have a clue really! If someone could please get back to me on if I should add wet food to his diet and if this food has the proper nutrients for a cat? I just realized that I didn't add this in last time. My cat drinks about half a decent sized water bowl a day. Plus whatever he can steal from what I am drinking. (usually not much.) Is this enough.

Comment: Ok, what exactly is the previous food? Is it so much unhealthier per se that he has to switch? if the previous food works well for all these years, why switch?

Comment: The food he is on has some pretty strange ingredients. I was told that if you wouldn't eat it (aside from the flavour obviously) you shouldn't feed it to your cat. Here is the food: http://www.petsmart.ca/cat/dry-food/royal-canin-feline-care-nutrition-digestive-care-adult-cat-food-zid36-2480/cat-36-catid-200028

Comment: I actually think the brand you linked is what my vet sells in his practice; so i would just stick with that, it looks like any other type of cat food imo and if it works well with your cat i wouldn't worry to much about wet food. I also support Mhwombat's answer. Changing isn't necessarily improving.

Comment: Oh yea, not that relevant, but i work in a meat processing factory for human consumption; you'd be surprised how much of that cat foods ingredients also goes into human food.

Comment: Is the canned food that you want to add also the Royal Canin (prescription) food, or are you trying to add plain old Friskies (or whatever) to his diet?

Comment: "I was recently told that you should feed your cat wet food." I've read many contradictory information on this. Some suggest only dry food, others only wet food, others suggest to amply supply dry food but limit wet food to a short meal, ... Your cat has digestive issues, which can influence what food you should give him. Even if wet food is better for cats in general, it might not be better for _your_ cat specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any cat food sold in the U.S. and E.U. and labeled "complete" - even the inexpensive brands you buy at the grocery store - is required by law to provide all the nutrition that a cat needs at any stage of life. The brand of food your cat is on is well-respected.

> The food he is on has some pretty strange ingredients.

Not really. Most of the ingredients with strange names are vitamins, amino acids, or important minerals which your cat needs. Is there a particular ingredient that you're concerned about?

Bear in mind that since pets generally eat the same food every day, manufacturers must add vitamins, amino acids, and minerals to their food. That's because there's no natural food that provides everything.

> I don't want to "switch" I just want to add wet food into his daily meals because of it's health benefits.

My understanding is that there are some benefits to wet food, and some benefits to dry food. You can feed both, but dry food alone is fine as long as your pet drinks water. It sounds like you had to try a bunch of foods before you found one that your cat tolerates, so I'd be tempted to stick with that and not rock the boat.

Since your cat has digestive issues, it's essential that you make any dietary changes **slowly**. Start with a tiny amount of the new food. The next day, mix in a bit more of the new food. Repeat until you've made the desired change.

Comment: It sounds like your cat is drinking enough. The amount he drinks will probably vary with the heat and humidity, so just make sure you always provide more water than he needs.

Answer (score 1):

My 13 year old cat used to have the same issues and then I found out that feeding her dry kitten food works well. I've been feeding her this for quite a few years now and she is able to digest this food much better. I would give it a try if I were you.